# "so much to do"

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language, countability

Why is it usually "so much to do" than "so many to do"?
 Isn't it "things to do"?

I don't mind to think that a certain number of things can be considered as a certain *amount* of things, though the other way around is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have to be (countable) "things to do".  It could be (uncountable) "stuff to do" or "work to do".